# BooleanToHiddenVisibility methods not being executed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My XAML in MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<r:RibbonGroup x:Name="LockDataRibbonGroup" Header="Data Editing" Visibility="{Binding   IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">

class BooleanToHiddenVisibility : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Boolean)
        {
            return ((bool)value) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        return value;
    }
    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Visibility visibility = (Visibility) value;
        if (visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
}
```

View Model:

```
private bool _isVisible = true;
public bool IsVisible
{
    get { return _isVisible; }
    set { _isVisible = value; }
}

if(somecondition)
    IsVisible = false;
```

Did does not work. When I put breakpoints on Conver and ConvertBack they are never hit. What am I missing? is this something to do with visibility. My BooleanToHiddenVisibility class is in a Helpers folder. My MainWindow.xaml is in a View folder.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared your class as "class BooleanToHiddenVisibility : IValueConverter" but you have used the internal "BooleanToVisibilityConverter".

Replace Below :

```
<Window.Resources>
  <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

With This :

```
<Window.Resources>
  <BooleanToHiddenVisibility x:Key="BooleanToHiddenVisibility " />
</Window.Resources>
```

And use the x:Key="BooleanToHiddenVisibility " as key in XAML and ofcourse implement [INotifyProipertyChanged](http://wpftutorial.net/INotifyPropertyChanged.html)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to indicate the property has changed:

```
private bool _isVisible = true;
public bool IsVisible
{
    get { return _isVisible; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _isVisible)
        {
            _isVisible = value; 

            this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsVisible");
        }
    }
}
```

`RaisePropertyChanged` would be the method that raises the `PropertyChanged` event from  [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I'm also playing around with MVVM Light toolkit. Is there a way to use the mvvm toolkit to avoid RaisePropertyChanged for this instance?

Comment: You can change the line of code to set { Set(() => IsVisible, ref _isVisible, value); } when using MVVM Light. Or set { Set("IsVisible", ref _isVisible, value); }.